# How to exit a method in ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, methods, actionlistener, jtextfield

I have an `ActionListener` connected to a `JTextField` and  want to type something so that it will exit the method the `ActionListener` is in.

Code:

```
main() {
    Security(x,x,x);
}
public void Security(JTextArea out, JTextField in) {
        in.setText("");
        in.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (in.getText().contains("exitsys")) {
                    out.append("Security:Security System Deactivated\n");
                    return;
                }
                in.setText("");
            }
        });
        out.append("Security:Security System Activated\n");
        fileWrite(":SYSTEM_INITIATED@" + time(), out);
    }
```

I want to type `"exitsys"` and return to the main class method `"main()"`.

The `fileWrite` method uses a `PrintWriter` to output data.

QUESTION SUMMARY: I try calling return; but it does not return to the method main(), how do i fix this?

Comment: *"..and want to type something and it exits the method the Actionlistener is in."* Wait ..what?  If the user is 'typing something' the code flow is typically not 'in' an `actionPerformed(..)` method.

Comment: Have you looked at using a dialog of some kind? Take a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: the user presses enter when inputting text to the JTextField, i got this code from a oracle book, so i assumed it was correct.  I just want to return because whrn i call return; it doesent exit the method Security()

Comment: There editted the question it should help :)

Comment: *"..whrn i call return"*  When is that?  The code above does not attempt to `return` or `break` at any point.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Also 1) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is a `CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 2)  Don't use confusing names for classes.  This class seems to be called `main` when it might be called `ApplicationLaunchpad` or something more descriptive.  There is also possible confusion between a `main` class and the `public static void main(String[])` **method.**

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson i just have bad habit of the class main and the method!

Comment: *"i just have bad habit"*  Now (sooner rather than later) is the time to stop bad habits..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what you need is some kind of modal dialog, which will allow you to, effectively, halt the execution of your program at the point the dialog is made visible until the dialog is dismissed (closed), when the execution will continue...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
                dialog.setTitle("Testing");
                dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                dialog.add(new TestPane());
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                dialog.setVisible(true);

                System.out.println("Now back in the main...");
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField field;

        public TestPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            field = new JTextField(10);
            field.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if ("exitsys".equals(field.getText())) {
                        SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(field).dispose();
                    }
                }
            });

            add(field);

        }

    }

}
```

See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks! that took me awhile to understand, i usually put invokeLater in the main method and then make my components and frames in the Test() method.  One quick question the Test() considered a method or something else, because i don't know what to call it?

Comment: `Test()` is a constructor, I get out of the `static` restrictions of `main` as quickly as I can, as it reduces problems related to `static` and `non-static` issues, but that's just me

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of dialogs for my application, but i still think they are pretty cool.

Comment: Dialogs tend to be short lived, information gathering platforms, which allow you to show small snippets of information to the user (such as a error/information message) or gather small pieces of information from the user you might need (like a login dialog). Generally speaking, you should limit the number of "main" windows you have, as it can quickly become confusing to the user...

Comment: The point of my program was to use the GPIO on a Raspberry Pi and play a MP3 sound when a magnet switch attached to the door was triggered.

Comment: I understand the dialog idea now, thanks! i just have that pop up and when its entered the program keep running, sorry took me a min to wrap my head around that.

Comment: how do i set the size of a dialog window? I am usung mac OSX and for some reason the window only appears with 0X0 dimensions (only shows the exit, minimize, and maximize buttons), but when i resize it i can see the elements i added.  Any Ideas?